# how to check if a request param/query param is passed in the request in Spring MVC app?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two different requests to handle

1. `localhost:8080/myapp/status`
2. `localhost:8080/myapp/status?v`

Please note that in the second request, just a request param is passed. No value is required to be set for it. That is the requirement.

How will I handle this in my controller?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void status(
                       @RequestParam(value = "v", required = "false") final String verbose) {

   //check if v is in query params
          ...logic
   //else 
         ..logic
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `param` in the mapping?

Comment: @chrylis: sorry, I am not clear what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`HttpServlerRequest.getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void status(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean verbose = request.getParameterMap().containsKey("v");
    if (verbose) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```